# Duplicate values returned from SQL JOIN Statement

Tags: sql

I'm getting duplicate account numbers when I user an inner join with transaction table. How do limit it so I do not see duplicate account numbers.

```
SELECT     A01_AccountMaster.AccountNumber, A01_AccountMaster.FamilyMemberType,
           A01_AccountMaster.AccountType, A01_AccountMaster.FamilyId, 
           A01_AccountMaster.Title, A01_AccountMaster.FirstName, 
           A01_AccountMaster.MiddleName, A01_AccountMaster.LastName,
           A01_AccountMaster.Suffix, A01_AccountMaster.OrganizationName,
           A01_AccountMaster.Status,
           T01_TransactionMaster.Date,
           T01_TransactionMaster.AccountNumber AS T01_Accountnumber  
FROM       A01_AccountMaster
INNER JOIN T01_TransactionMaster
      ON A01_AccountMaster.AccountNumber = T01_TransactionMaster.AccountNumber
WHERE      (A01_AccountMaster.Title = 'The')
           AND (T01_TransactionMaster.Date between '01/01/2010' and '09/12/2012')
ORDER BY   AccountNumber;
```

Comment: ["Select distinct"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)?

Comment: Duplicates with joins mean that you either have valid several record in joined table per row in main table, or you've just composed your join `ON` condition wrong.

Comment: @paulsm4: that's a terrible advice. `DISTINCT` is never a correct solution in such cases

Comment: Without a result set how do we know they are duplicates?

Comment: @Jon Mitten: any reason to select garbage and beautify it? Why not just select correct the data at first? If you're applying `DISTINCT` to more than 1 field (most often it's one, more in very rare and specific cases) - it's a sign you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: You can't. Unless you agree with your customers that they can only have ONE transaction every two years per account number. Perhaps you'd better explain what you're trying to achieve here (e.g. "I want the names of all users who entered at least one transaction in this period; if they entered more, I want the first/last/...")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to summarize the transaction table to get what you want from it.

To aggregate the data, use a query such as this:

```
select am.*, tm.NumTransactions
from A01_AccountMaster am join
     (select AccountNumber, count(*) as numtransactions
      from T01_TransactionMaster
      group by AccountNumber
     ) tm
     on am.AccountNumber = tm.AccountNumber
where . . .
```

Doing the aggregation at the subquery level simplifies the overall query, since you don't have to do a group by with lots of fields.  Also, if you introduce more tables, aggregating at the subquery level can prevent problems caused by interactions between the records in the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you retrieve elements from the transaction table like "T01_TransactionMaster.Date" and 2 transactions can belong to the same account, it means that for 1 account row you can have multiple transaction dates returned.

How do you expect the computer to return the appropriate data?

You have different choices.

Like removing the select statements of the transaction columns and use DISTINCT which seems a bit heavy for such a select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A01_AccountMaster.AccountNumber, A01_AccountMaster.FamilyMemberType, A01_AccountMaster.AccountType, A01_AccountMaster.FamilyId, A01_AccountMaster.Title, A01_AccountMaster.FirstName, A01_AccountMaster.MiddleName, A01_AccountMaster.LastName, A01_AccountMaster.Suffix, A01_AccountMaster.OrganizationName, A01_AccountMaster.Status
FROM A01_AccountMaster 
INNER JOIN T01_TransactionMaster on (A01_AccountMaster.AccountNumber) = T01_TransactionMaster.AccountNumber 
WHERE (A01_AccountMaster.Title = 'The') 
and (T01_TransactionMaster.Date between '01/01/2010' and '09/12/2012') 
order by AccountNumber
```

OR
If you need to return the transaction date, you can have different strategies using groupBy on all account fields, and an aggregation on the transaction fields (for exemple, returning the maximum date to have the date of the last transaction for an account)

```
SELECT A01_AccountMaster.AccountNumber,A01_AccountMaster.AccountType,........,max(T01_TransactionMaster.Date)
FROM A01_AccountMaster 
INNER JOIN T01_TransactionMaster on (A01_AccountMaster.AccountNumber) = T01_TransactionMaster.AccountNumber 
WHERE (A01_AccountMaster.Title = 'The') 
and (T01_TransactionMaster.Date between '01/01/2010' and '09/12/2012') 
group by A01_AccountMaster.AccountNumber,A01_AccountMaster.AccountType,........
order by AccountNumber
```